# Functions using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to implement an excel calculator web app which performs functions on an existing Excel file located on a OneDrive for Business folder. I've been trying to implement it in Ruby as my target platform is Rails. this is from [Excel REST API on the Microsoft Graph](https://dev.office.com/blogs/power-your-apps-with-the-new-excel-rest-api)

```rb
response = HTTParty.post('..../workbook/functions/pmt', headers: {
      'Authorization' => 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN, '
      Content - Type ' => '
      application / json ' },
      body: '{ "rate": 0.035, "nper": 20, "pv": -2000 }') puts response
```

With this response:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#workbookFunctionResult",
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.workbookFunctionResult",
  "@odata.id": ".../drive/root/children('test.xlsx')/workbook/functions/pmt()",
  "error": null,
  "value": 140.722153566052
}
```

I'm trying to get other functions like `sum` using a similar format

```rb
response = HTTParty.post('.../worbook/functions/sum', headers: {
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  },
  body: '{ "number1" : 200, "number2" : 300 }')
```

But I get the error

```json
"error": {
  "code": "InvalidArgument",
  "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about exploring more of the API where it actually matters because the documentation is non-existent.

I especially don't know how to read and write individual cells / ranges in an Excel document to get Functions calculated out of them.

Has anybody managed to get a decent working example of anything around this? Can anyone suggest any links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the documentation on Excel Functions under the [Workbook](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/workbook#functions) topic. There is also a complete list of [Excel Functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188) available.

For functions that take a range of cells, you can pass in the values as an array. For example, to use `sum` you would pass in:

```json
{
  "values" :  [100,100,50,100] 
}
```

This will return:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#workbookFunctionResult",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.workbookFunctionResult",
    "@odata.id": "/users({user-id})/drive/items({item-id})/workbook/functions/sum()",
    "error": null,
    "value": 350
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer? how do I pass an address range to it? this isn't really documented or at least for people who rarely use this - it isn't very intuitive